# How can I search this object to see if a user has a permission?

Tags: javascript, json, object, search, recursion

Given that I have:

```
var permissions = {
    'blog': {
    'article' : ['add_article', 'view_articles']
  },
  'gallery': {
    'images' : ['upload_image', 'view_other_user_images']
  }
}

var permissionsChecker = function(permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
    this.hasPermissions = function (permissionsString) {
      // permissionsString is in this.permissions
      // return true
  }
}
```

How can I search in the array within that object to check that I have a certain permission? I want to be able to search by giving a string like so:

```
'blog.article.add_article' or 'gallery.images.view_other_user_images'
```

Comment: How about `gallery.images.includes('view_other_user_images')`? not that much difference

Comment: Start by getting your general syntax correctly...

Comment: use **No semicolons** [It's](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding) [fine.](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) [Really!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsfbh17Ax9I) and it will solve your syntax

Comment: @Endless *no* semicolons at all isn't a solution either

Comment: @Bergi it was before he edited/corrected his own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding correctly, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var permissionsChecker = function(permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
    this.hasPermissions = function (permissionsString) {
      var [section, subsection, permission] = permissionsString.split('.');
      if(this.permissions[section]){
        if(this.permissions[section][subsection]){
          return this.permissions[section][subsection].indexOf(permission) > -1;
        }
      }
      return false;
  }; 
}
var checker = new permissionsChecker(permissions);
checker.hasPermission('add_article');//true
checker.hasPermission('destroy_world');//false
```

Comment: Thank you for an actual helpful comment/answer that was not patronising :)

Comment: In the case where I pass in a section and/or a subsection that does not exist, how should I handle this elegantly?

Comment: @JohnathanAu I've posted an update reflecting that comment.